# Publish Azure functions (model v2) don't set triggers (functions)?

Tags: python, azure, webdeploy

Tried to search Google/Bing chat/Stack and didn't find a solution to my issue.

I have the following environment:

IDE: PyCharm, CLI: microsoft az/func (running fine). Defined local with `func init`. Created the function in azure function. The settings from local.settings.json are the same with one online. The files from application are current published. The venv is the same for entire project but i put a separate requirements.txt in folder.

The function locally is running nicely with `func start`

But the published function with `<function folder>\func azure functionapp publish ...` don't have triggers / functions.

My functions is like this:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

from py_pdf import PdfOcrReader

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


@app.function_name(name="healthcheck")
@app.route(route="healthcheck")
def healthcheck(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("Status OK", status_code=200)


@app.function_name(name="pypdf")
@app.route(route="pypdf")
def pypdf_api(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    file = req.files.get('file')
    if not file:
        return func.HttpResponse("No file found in the request.", status_code=400)

    # process file
    pdf_obj = PdfOcrReader(file)

    json_out = {
        "pdf_text": pdf_obj.pdf_text,
        "ocr_text": pdf_obj.ocr_computer_vision()
    }
    json_out.update(pdf_obj.metadata)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        str(json_out), status_code=200
    )
```

The host.json is looking like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

P.S: The loggout when `func publish` looks like

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.10.4/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.
Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 8 sec(s).
Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.

[=============================================================-] 1250/1250 100%

Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
        compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments,
        compressed xattrs, compressed ids
        duplicates are removed
Filesystem size 40794.51 Kbytes (39.84 Mbytes)
        74.13% of uncompressed filesystem size (55031.18 Kbytes)
Inode table size 10917 bytes (10.66 Kbytes)
        31.05% of uncompressed inode table size (35154 bytes)
Directory table size 9962 bytes (9.73 Kbytes)
        35.27% of uncompressed directory table size (28244 bytes)
        root (0)
Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-....zip located
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for ....azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
Syncing triggers...
Functions in ....:
(venv) PS C:\Users\civan\PycharmProjects\....\....>
```

I don't know if it relevant, but this is a logstream when I published a change in host.json:

```
Connected!
2023-06-06T07:57:50Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-06-06T07:57:50Z   [Information]   DrainMode mode enabled
2023-06-06T07:57:50Z   [Information]   Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
2023-06-06T07:57:50Z   [Information]   Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
2023-06-06T07:57:50Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-06-06T07:58:02Z   [Information]   File change of type 'Changed' detected for 'C:\Users\civan\PycharmProjects\...\...\host.json'
2023-06-06T07:58:02Z   [Information]   Host configuration has changed. Signaling restart
2023-06-06T07:58:02Z   [Information]   File change of type 'Changed' detected for 'C:\Users\civan\PycharmProjects\...\...\host.json'
2023-06-06T07:58:02Z   [Information]   Host configuration has changed. Signaling restart
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000021706BBA'.
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Verbose]   Initiating background SyncTriggers operation
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   1 functions found
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   1 functions found
2023-06-06T07:58:10Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2023-06-06T07:58:14Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-06-06T07:58:14Z   [Information]   DrainMode mode enabled
2023-06-06T07:58:14Z   [Information]   Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
2023-06-06T07:58:14Z   [Information]   Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Information]   DrainMode mode enabled
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Information]   Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Information]   Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Information]   DrainMode mode enabled
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Information]   Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
2023-06-06T07:59:09Z   [Information]   Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
2023-06-06T07:59:54Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-06-06T07:59:54Z   [Information]   DrainMode mode enabled
2023-06-06T07:59:54Z   [Information]   Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
2023-06-06T07:59:54Z   [Information]   Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
2023-06-06T08:00:26Z   [Information]   Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000008EA10CF8'.
2023-06-06T08:00:55Z   [Information]   Host Status: {
  "id": "ocroperations",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "4.21.3.3",
  "versionDetails": "4.21.3+2e42e3beb40b89d4f5d3dd962f3a5d420d376d71",
  "platformVersion": "",
  "instanceId": "54108609-638216349727465766",
  "computerName": "",
  "processUptime": 267075,
  "functionAppContentEditingState": "NotAllowed",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be because the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` app setting is incorrectly set. This specifies whether the function app should be run from a package file or from files in the `wwwroot` directory.

Use below `AzCLI` command to update the above app setting.

```bash
az functionapp config appsettings set --name <functionappname> --resource-group <xxxxRG> --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1
```

[image]

You can check this [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-app-settings.md) for more information on function app settings configuration.

This issue could also be caused by the deployment package file. Refer [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package.md) to run functions from the package file.

*If still the issue persists, try creating a new python trigger Azure function and deploy it after clearing the cache.*

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution but in the meantime used the following procedure:
- work in pycharm, - run it in vscode !!!!C'est la vie :)